# When writeToSocket nothing happen

Tags: apache-flink

I just following this https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/socket/SocketWindowWordCount.java

and adding some part to write the result into socket

```
    windowCounts
        .writeToSocket("localhost", 7777, new SerializationSchema<WordWithCount>() {
          @Override
          public byte[] serialize(WordWithCount wordWithCount) {
            return wordWithCount.toString().getBytes();
          }
        });
```

and i don't get anything on my localhost(port 7777). is there something that i missed? thank you

Comment: How do You check for Outputs ? Have You tried printing the outputs to see if thereare any ?

Comment: Just by using netcat
`nc -l 7777`
but right now i can see the output. by restarting the jar. Not sure what happen there

Comment: But did You try to see if You have any output at all if You print it ??

Comment: now i can see the output on 7777